# LazyLoad is not hiding placeholder img Rails 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not too fond of the '**lazyload-rails**' gem, but it seems to be the only one available with this functionality. I wrapped the lazyload method itself, in a turbolinks load method call. The photos themselves are fading in correctly, but the placeholder is not hiding in the container, and only showing up when an image is being loaded. How can I hide the placeholder image when no pictures are present or loading on the server back-end?

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 post-image">
      <%= image_tag post.post_photo.feed_preview, class: 'd-flex align-self-start mr-3 img-fluid rounded', lazy: true %>
      <span class="badge badge-default"><%= fa_icon 'clock-o' %>
        <small><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</small></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

lazyload.rb

```
Lazyload::Rails.configure do |config|
  config.placeholder = "/placeholder70x70.gif"
end
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
        $("img").lazyload({
            effect : "fadeIn"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this approach isn't the greatest, but a simple if statement checks if the image is present, and when its not. The placeholder automatically disappears.

updated html

```
<% if post.post_photo.present? %>
<%= image_tag post.post_photo.feed_preview %>
<% else %>
<% end %>
```